# jQuery form populator not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been working on a jQuery bookmarklet to populate a long online form and I've been testing code pieces as go in jsfiddle.  The following is of course the last piece and it doesn't want to work.  Any ideas?

```
<div id="treatmentGoals" class="moduleRow">
  <div class="moduleCol">
    <table id="treatmentGoalsTable">
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
        <td><strong>Time Frame</strong></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="text-align:right; font-weight:bold;">1:
        </td>
        <td>
          <input class="field1" style="" type="text" name="frm_TrtmntGoalTxt1|spWritefrmVarchar|0" onFocus="$(this).attr('name','frm_TrtmntGoalTxt1|spWritefrmVarchar|1');$(this).css('background-color','white')" id="frm_TrtmntGoalTxt1" size="" maxlength="170" onblur=""
          value="" onKeyUp="if (event.keyCode == 13){modifyForm('save', undefined, false, 72960)};" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input class="field2" style="" type="text" name="frm_TrtmntGoalTime1|spWritefrmVarchar|0" onFocus="$(this).attr('name','frm_TrtmntGoalTime1|spWritefrmVarchar|1');$(this).css('background-color','white')" id="frm_TrtmntGoalTime1" size="" maxlength="15"
          onblur="" value="" onKeyUp="if (event.keyCode == 13){modifyForm('save', undefined, false, 72960)};" />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the javascript I've been using for the rest of the page elements to populate them.

```
$('#frm_TrtmntGoalTxt1').val('Pt will be safe and independent all mobility around the house for improved functional mobility to decrease risk of falls');
$('#frm_TrtmntGoalTime1').val(' weeks');
```

I'm just not sure what's changed in this last code section.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: the last code section is HTML, not javascript.. html doesn't do anything... what did you think would ha[[en?

Comment: also, this may be useful: http://blog.geneticcoder.com/2015/10/31/javascript-browser-button-maker/

Comment: this code works fine. what is it that you try to do and doesn't work?

Comment: The jQuery at the bottom should populate the input fields with the provided values.  I'm running this in jsFiddle and it doesn't populate the fields.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not sure why the abbreviated code wasn't working in jsFiddle, but I did discover the problem with the complete code section which was missing a trailing quotation mark.  Thanks anyway.